# Lista Simplesmente Encadeada em C - Não compila corretamente

Tags: c, lista, lista-encadeada

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

typedef struct nodo Nodo;

struct nodo{
  int valor;
  Nodo *proximo;
};

void cria_lista(Nodo **pp_ini, Nodo **pp_fim) {
  *pp_ini = NULL;
  *pp_fim = NULL;
  puts("Lista Criada!");
}

void destroi_lista(Nodo **pp_ini, Nodo **pp_fim) {
  Nodo *nodo_aux;
  nodo_aux = *pp_ini;
  while (nodo_aux) {
    *pp_ini = (*pp_ini)->proximo;
    free(nodo_aux);
    nodo_aux = (*pp_ini);
  }
  *pp_fim = NULL;
}

void imprime_lista_inicio(Nodo *p_ini) {
  Nodo *p = p_ini;
  if (p_ini == NULL) {
    printf("Lista vazia.\n");
    return;
  }
  while (p) {
    printf("Valor do nodo = %d\n", p->valor);
    p = p->proximo;
  }
}

void insere_inicio(Nodo **pp_ini, Nodo **pp_fim, int valor) {
  Nodo *nodo_aux;
  nodo_aux = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
  if (nodo_aux) {
    nodo_aux->valor = valor;
    nodo_aux->proximo = *pp_ini;
    if (*pp_ini == NULL) {
      *pp_fim = nodo_aux;
    }
    *pp_ini = nodo_aux;
  }
}

void insere_fim(Nodo **pp_ini, Nodo **pp_fim, int valor) {
  Nodo *nodo_aux;
  nodo_aux = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
  if (nodo_aux) {
    nodo_aux->valor = valor;
    nodo_aux->proximo = NULL;
    Nodo *p_fim, *p_ini;
    p_ini = *pp_ini;
    p_fim = *pp_fim;
    if (p_ini == NULL) {
      p_ini = nodo_aux;
      p_fim = nodo_aux;
    }
    else {
      p_fim->proximo = nodo_aux;
      p_fim = nodo_aux;
    }
    *pp_ini = p_ini;
    *pp_fim = p_fim;
  }
}

void remove_inicio(Nodo **pp_ini, Nodo **pp_fim){
    Nodo *nodo_aux;
    if(*pp_ini){
        if(*pp_ini==*pp_fim){
            destroi_lista(pp_fim, pp_fim);
        }else{
            nodo_aux = *pp_ini;
            nodo_aux = nodo_aux->proximo;
            *pp_ini = nodo_aux;
            free(nodo_aux);
        }
    }else{
        printf("Nodo Inexistente");
    }
}

//void remove_fim(Nodo **pp_ini, Nodo **pp_fim){
//    Nodo *nodo_aux, *x;
//    if(*pp_fim){
//        if(*pp_ini == *pp_fim){
//            destroi_lista(pp_fim, pp_fim);
//        }else{
//            x = *pp_ini;
//            while(x){
//                x = x->proximo;
//            }
//        }
//    }
//    else{
//        printf("Nodo Inexistente");
//    }
//}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

Nodo *nodo_inicio, *nodo_fim;

puts("");
puts("1)");
cria_lista(&nodo_inicio, &nodo_fim);

puts("");
puts("2)");
insere_inicio(&nodo_inicio, &nodo_fim, 7);
insere_inicio(&nodo_inicio, &nodo_fim, 6);
insere_inicio(&nodo_inicio, &nodo_fim, 5);
imprime_lista_inicio(nodo_inicio);

puts("");
puts("3)");
imprime_lista_inicio(nodo_inicio);

puts("");
puts("4)");
insere_inicio(&nodo_inicio, &nodo_fim, 4);
imprime_lista_inicio(nodo_inicio);

puts("");
puts("5)");
insere_fim(&nodo_inicio, &nodo_fim, 77);
imprime_lista_inicio(nodo_inicio);

puts("");
puts("6)");
remove_inicio(&nodo_inicio, &nodo_fim);
imprime_lista_inicio(nodo_inicio);

puts("");
puts("7)");
insere_inicio(&nodo_inicio, &nodo_fim, 33);
imprime_lista_inicio(nodo_inicio);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se retirar a ultima parte (7) ele compila normalmente, acredito que o problema esteja na função remove_inicio.

Comment: cole a mensagem de erro, normalmente na mensagem é mostrada também a linha que deu erro...além disso, sem a mensagem de erro fica difícil alguém tentar ajudar

Comment: n tem mensagem de erro, ele apenas entra em loop, imprimindo valores sem parar...

Comment: mas o título de sua pergunta é "erro ao compilar"...

Comment: pronto, agora ja pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Em **remove_inicio()**, a seção de código abaixo está dando margem a um loop eterno para a função subsequente que vocẽ está usando (**insere_inicio()** lá no fim de main)

```
     nodo_aux = *pp_ini;
     nodo_aux = nodo_aux->proximo;
     *pp_ini = nodo_aux;
     free(nodo_aux);
```

Substitua por:

```
     nodo_aux = (*pp_ini)->proximo;
     free(*pp_ini);
     *pp_ini = nodo_aux;
```

Seu código possui outros problemas e está desnecessariamente complexo para uma lista simpes, mas fica como exercício para você :)

Answer (score -1):

na função remove_inicio, retirei o "free(nodo_aux);" e compilou corretamente.